# React.JS - Normal Functions or Arrow Functions in Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

Today in React it is much more common to use functional components with React hooks rather then class components.  I am wondering, though, whether or not it is better to use a normal function or error function when creating a react component in a functional component.

For example, this:

```
// normal function
function MyComponent(props) {
 ...
}
```

or this:

```
// arror function
const MyComponent = (props) => {
 ...
}
```

There are discussions of this question before as relate to class components, but I was not able to find any information with regards to functional components.

I am wondering, therefore, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.  Please note, I'm not looking for personal preference, but rather factual differences and/or benefits of one approach over the other.

Any thoughts?